# Separating models in Flask-SQLAlchemy to another file breaks PyDev import detection

Tags: python, flask, pydev, flask-sqlalchemy

I am learning Flask and when I try to separate my app to more modules, for no apparent reason PyDev starts to report `Undefined variable from import`. However, the code still works.

First, I have added `flask` to Forced Builtins first so PyDev parses extensions dynamically. This way PyDev does not report `flask.ext...` imports.

Everything is fine with this setup:

**templates/index.py**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    {% for user in all_users %}
      <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**main_old.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username="", email=""):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email  

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///test.db"
db.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(User("John Doe", "john.doe@example.com"))
    db.session.add(User("Bill Smith", "smith.bill@example.com"))
    db.session.commit()
    all_users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', all_users=all_users)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now I separate **main_old.py** into **main.py** and **models.py** like this:

**models.py**

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username="", email=""):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from models import db, User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///test.db"
db.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(User("John Doe", "john.doe@example.com"))
    db.session.add(User("Bill Smith", "smith.bill@example.com"))
    db.session.commit()
    all_users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', all_users=all_users)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It is equivalent, but I get `Undefined variable from import: query` on `all_users = User.query.all()` line.
Why the PyDev import detection breaks like this? Why did it work in one file? Is there a way to fix this? Is there workaround other than `@UndefinedVariable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not know why is this happening, but workaround exists.

Use recommended `all_users = db.session.query(User).all()` instead of `all_users = User.all()`.